# print distinct elements and original list of elements

Tags: java

i want to print all unique elements and print the original list but it only prints the distinct elements help me heres my codes...

```
 static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list) {

        // Store unique items in result.
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // Record encountered Strings in HashSet.
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        // Loop over argument list.
        for (String item : list) {

            // If String is not in set, add it to the list and the set.
            if (!set.contains(item)) {
                result.add(item);
                set.add(item);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("full");
        words.add("fill");
        words.add("full");
         words.add("fall");
          words.add("fill");
           words.add("fell");
            words.add("fall");
              ArrayList<String> unique = removeDuplicates(words);
        for (String element : unique) {

            System.out.print("\t" +element);

    }


}
}
```

the output must be this:

Elements inside the list[full,fill,fill,full,fall,fill,fell,fall]

distinc elements[full,fill,fall,fell]

Comment: Please include some examples of what you want the output to look like, and what it actually looks like.

Comment: as a side note,  `if (!set.contains(item))` is redundant because a `Set` doesn't allow duplicates anyway meaning you can just keep adding rather than checking if it doesn't contain it.... you can simplify your code to `if (set.add(item)) 
                result.add(item);`

Comment: the output must look like this: Elements inside the list[full,fill,fill,full,fall,fill,fell,fall]

distinc elements[full,fill,fall,fell]

Comment: You don't need a set at all, just  `if ( !result.contains(item) ) result.add(item) return result`;

Comment: suppose you doesn't seem to print the original list. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words.toArray()));`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu you could just do `System.out.println(words);`

Comment: Better to delete the question. If you forgot to write a print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You eliminate duplicates by testing `( if ! set.contains(item) )` 
so you will get this result:

```
full , fill , fall , fell
```

[image: Example result]

if you want to get the result:

```
full,fill,fill,full,fall,fill,fell,fall
```

you shouldn't test `( ! set.conaitns(item) )`

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it doesn't print the original list.  You didn't write any code to do that.

Comment: hehe sorry i forgot to write

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you could use the Stream API to do it for you.

I believe this would be done simply like :

```
list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

public class UniqueArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {

List initialList =Arrays.asList("eBay", "paypal", "google", "eBay","google", "paypal");

System.out.printf("\nInitial list: %s%n",initialList);

sortList(initialList);

}

public static void sortList (List myList){

Set hashsetList = newHashSet(myList);

System.out.printf("\nUnique values using HashSet: %s%n", hashsetList);

}

}

Output be like:-

Initial list: [eBay, paypal, google, eBay, google,paypal]

Unique values using HashSet: [google, paypal,eBay]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.